# Ruby - Nesting objects through input values

Tags: ruby

Hello my fellow companion!

What I'm trying to achieve is a system by which an Order form is compiled in two ways:

1. by fullfilling its own attributes (:sender_name, :sender_mobile etc..)
2. by selecting products through the price labels attached on them.

After a while of poking here and there, I managed to display the product list on the order form. Here the 3 models and the views

models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sender_comment, :sender_email, :sender_mobile, :sender_name, :order_attributes

  has_many :products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    attr_accessible :product_name, :product_description, :prices_attributes, :order_id

    has_many :prices

    accepts_nested_attributes_for  :prices
end
```

models/price.rb

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product

    attr_accessible :product_id, :price_label, :price_amount, :price_checked, :how_many_prices, :products_attributes
end
```

views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sender_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :sender_name %>
  </div>

  # [...] other order's fields... 

  <%= f.fields_for :product do |builder|  %>
    <%= render "products_field", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

views/orders/_products.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
    <td><%= p.product_name %></td>
<td><%= p.product_description %></td><br />
        <% p.prices.each do |price| %>
            <td><%= price.price_label %></td><br />
            <td><%= price.price_amount %></td><br />
            <td><input type="radio" class="order_bool" name="<%= p.product_name %>" <% if price.price_checked == true; puts "SELECTED"; end %> value="<%= price.price_amount%>"/></td><br />
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Products and relatives prices are printed in the Order form, yet once selected they're not saved as order_attributes; along with the order's attributes, every radio selected generates an object like this

```
[#<Product id: nil, order_id: 23, product_name: nil, product_description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

How can I convert the selected products into effective order_attributes?

This is my first project with OOP and that I'm learning all by myself, with a very few help but from the internet. Please don't be too harsh!

Also feel free to change the title if you don't consider it appropriate enough; english is not my native language and i find very difficult to recap this issue in just a few words.

Thanks for the patient :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in order attributes? You can always access the products of a particular order by order_1.products (order_1 is an instance of Order). That will give you all the products in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your current `_products_fields` partial isn't even attached to the `form` object. You're building arbitrary inputs right now. See [`form_for` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [`fields_for` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) and [`radio_button` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button).

***Note**: When you use `f.method_name` you're actually going to call the [`FormBuilder` versions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-radio_button) of the method and not the `FormHelper` versions. Since the `FormHelper` version has more and still relevant documentation that's the better version. Just omit the `object_name` parameter.*

I think changing a these lines should do the trick:

**Form Partial:**

```
<%= f.fields_for :products, @products do |builder|  %>
    <%= render "products_field", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

**Products Fields Partial**

```
# 'f' is the variable passed in using ':f => builder'
# So 'f' = builder

# f.object is accessing the object were building the fields for
<td><%= f.object.product_name %></td>
<td><%= f.object.product_description %></td><br />
<% f.object.prices.each do |price| %>
  <td><%= price.price_label %></td><br />
  <td><%= price.price_amount %></td><br />
  <td><%= f.radio_box("price", price.price_amount %></td><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: -> Azolo It seems like the each method take the application out the field for method; it saves the selected objects, yet it does it away from the main utf object: i can see from the parameters. How could i declare the @product variable in the "new" method, so that I know it will be put through the right hash if radio is true? At the present moment, it takes product_attributes and see their ids..yet he doesn't perceive as its own the prices nested attributes; I'm sure it's something stupid in the controller. Can I eventually pm you?